# Make an object by calling a method in java

Tags: java

if we have `MakeObject(String Name)` and calling this method will create `Object [Name] = new Object();`
How can we do that? And, if we want to move the `Object [Name]` from the method to a public variable in class `Clazz` ?
Example:

```
public class clazz {
    void MakeObject(String name) {
        Object[name] = new Object();
        [name].UpgradeToClassVariable(); // It should be a global variable
    }
}
```

Usage of `clazz` :

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        clazz c = new clazz();
        c.makeObject("Hello");
        c.Hello.doOperations(); // For example, if it's a String, doOperation() can be equals()
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: What would `Object[name]` actually be?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? You can do this by reflection, which is an advanced topic, but I suspect you're a newbie trying to figure out how to achieve the tasks you have, so it might be better to describe your goal so we can better answer your question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Object [Name]  not Object[Name]. Means name of the Object is [Name]

Comment: Well, you cannot have "[]" in names, since they have special meanings in java. What you _can_ do, though and what comes pretty close to what you seem to want is using a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: @Fildor [] is not a part of name, it's just like a variable depends on content of variable `Name`

Comment: @MoradAbdelrasheedMokhtar Ah, ok. No that doesn't work that way.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Let's make more clear, makeObject() will make a global object/variable like Integers,Arrays,Strings,etc..

Comment: @MoradAbdelrasheedMokhtar I wouldn't want to use a language, where that's actually possible. Look at what _problem_ you want to solve, then look at how java allows you to do that. Or figure another language suits you better...

Comment: You want to pass the name of a [java] class to method `MakeObject` as a string and you want method `MakeObject` to create an instance of that class. Is that correct?

Comment: @Abra Yes, If I want to `MakeObject("Hello")` A String object will be declared as a global variable with name Hello

Comment: Then it would appear that what you require is [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) or maybe using a [dynamic proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html)

Comment: @MoradAbdelrasheedMokhtar  If you're using a non-standard Java notation, please describe it better in the question text.

Answer (score 2):

In java, `.` is the dereference operator: Take the thing to the left of the 'dot'. This must be a reference. If it is a reference to nothing (null), a NullPointerException occurs.

The thing to the right is the message you send to it.

Thus, sending an object the message 'make yourself global' doesn't make any sense. Something like `MyClass.makeGlobal([name])` would, but java doesn't support this.

A class's structure is defined at compile time. You cannot, at runtime, add properties, or change a field from being instance to static.

The general idea of 'I want to add a property' still exists, but, not at the level you're talking about. Perhaps you want a `Map<String, Integer>` for example.

Take your second snippet:

```
clazz c = new clazz();
c.makeObject("Hello");
c.Hello.doOperations(); // For example, if it's a String, doOperation() can be equals()
```

That's just not how java works. Java will first compile code (`javac`), and then run it. javac **does not run any code**, it only compiles it. Thus, javac sees `c.Hello` and stops you right there, and says: Hello? What? I have no idea what you're talking about.

**That's why it is not possible to use a string literal to make a field like this.**

Java isn't javascript, or python, or ruby.

Comment: So we can say there's some kind of limitation that java doesn't support changing the structure in run-time ?

Comment: @ MoradAbdelrasheedMokhtar as far as structure and meta goes, sure. Like every language, there are structures you have to follow. As far as code concepts goes, you CAN do this, just not this way, you'd e.g. use a Map. java is turing complete, after all.